# change element for take back removed DOM elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I display data in `<td>` using Javascript? For example like this https://jsfiddle.net/m6e3aeq1/7/

Sorry if it's different or not same with this table.

```
| No | DATA1 | DATA2 | DELETE|
| 1  |   a   |   1   | DELETE|
| 2  |   b   |   2   | DELETE|
| 3  |   c   |   3   | DELETE|
```

For function delete it's already working. If I delete some row (E.g No 3) then use reset for take it back (this already works too).

for data reset:

```
a = new Array(['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']);
```

But the code is wrong (Not same like first time run code)

should be `| 1 | a | 1 |` **not** `| 1 | a,1 | a,1 |`

How change the code in `javascript`, I already try change element but still not correct.

```
$('#RESET').click(function() {
    $('#table').empty();
    $.each(a, function(index, element) {
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + (index + 1) + '<td>' + element + '</td><td>' + element + '</td><td><input type="button" class="DEL" value="DELETE"></td></tr>');
    });
});
```

How change second element `+ element +` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(a, function(index, element) {
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + (index + 1) + '<td>' + element[0] + '</td><td>' + element[1] + '</td><td><input type="button" class="DEL" value="DELETE"></td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a 2-d array. In order to iterate on 2-d array you need 2 loops Ex-

```
var arr = [["string", "string"], ["string", "string"]];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
 }
}
```

Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/kvw7a8j3/